# Why the Constructor is not called while cloning the object in java

Tags: java, constructor, clone

Why is the constructor is not called while cloning an object in java?

```java
Animal a = new Animal();
Animal b = (Animal)a.clone(); // This will not invoke Animal's constructor
```

If an object is created which is referenced by variable b then there would be some memory allocation and that should also involve calling the constructor, right?

But the documentation says, cloning an object does not involve calling the  constructor calling at all. Why?

Comment: What documentation says that?  I don't see anything to that effect in the API docs [for the Cloneable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) or [for Object#clone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone())

Comment: Which constructor would it call? Where would it find the value of the required arguments?

Comment: I believe that the .clone() method produces a copy of an existing object, for which the copy would have the exact same fields as the object being cloned, therefore it will find the values of the fields from the object being cloned (exact internal implementation I am unsure of). Since it is not constructing a brand new object, the constructor does not need to be called. The constructor is only called when the "new" keyword is involved (I believe).

Comment: If the clone() method is called for reference **a** , which is creating a new object which is referenced by **b**, then it should call class Animal's default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Also I cannot descibe why it is like it is. It seems that Java is just using another functionality to clone and make a copy of an object in constrast to creating new objects via new keyword. Using clone() means that the clone is created and all values are copied and the references are also copied. So clone() does not produce new objects with new references of the referenced objects. Maybe clone() is a kind of constructor?